# C# - Looking for WebService Security like Spring Security

Tags: c#, security, spring-security, webmethod

Is there any way to secure Web Methods in c# like Spring Security Annotations?

something like:

```
public interface MyWebService {

    @Secured("ROLE_USER")
    public void delete(int cid);

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Take a look at [authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc948343.aspx) for WCF.  Specifically, the .Net analog for controlling security is with the [PrincipalPermissionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermissionattribute.aspx).  For this to work, you will need to make sure your current context is associated with an identity, for instance, by requiring a username/password combination before connecting to your service and using those credentials to set the user account for the session.